# QT 5.6 QBluetooth: Either no Qt D-Bus found or no BlueZ headers

Tags: qtonpi

I am trying to get blue tooth working on my Raspberry Pi using the latest Raspbian image and the Qt 5.6 source. After recompiling twice (which takes about 35 hours) I keep getting the following error:

> Either no Qt D-Bus found or no BlueZ headers.

I have used [Native Build of Qt5 on a Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) in order to get everything compiled. I have also installed the following blue tooth packages:

- bluez
- libbluetooth3
- libbluetooth-dev
- libdbus-c++-dev

I found a similar thread [Bluetooth on Arm (Raspberri PI Debian 7)](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39609) in which I tried all the possible solution but nothing seems to work so far.

If I run `qmake -d` on the `qt5/qtconnectivity/config.tests/bluez` files I get the following output at the very end:

> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:8: calling built-in
>   $list(bluez) /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:8:
>   entering loop for PKGCONFIG_LIB over bluez
>
> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:8: loop iteration
>   "bluez" /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:8: entering
>   block /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: NOT
>   /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: evaluating test
>   function "packagesExist"
>
> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: calling
>   packagesExist(bluez) /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
>   entering block /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:191:
>   evaluating test function "contains"
>
> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:191: calling built-in
>   contains(QT_CONFIG, no-pkg-config)
>   /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:191: test function
>   returned true /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:191:
>   AND /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:191: flow control
>   statement 'return', aborting block
>
> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: test function
>   returned false /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10:
>   AND /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: evaluating
>   test function "error"
>
> /usr/local/qt5/mkspecs/features/link_pkgconfig.prf:10: calling
>   built-in error("bluez development package not found") Project ERROR:
>   bluez development package not found

but when I run the command `pkg-config --modversion bluez` it returns version 5.36 which would suggest it is able to find something. Running `pkg-config --libs` returns `-L/usr/local/lib -lbluetooth`.

Is there anyone who might know what causes my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the beginning of that Qt-Bug report I notice that you do not seem to have installed the `libdbus-1-dev` package that gets mentioned.